# Retrieving data from Facebook DOM vs FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to have your opinion concerning the retrieval of data on Facebook pages DOM. Is the practice is allowed? I feel that it's not very advisable.

For example, is there a way to recover some posts of visitors on pages, by applying a filtering upstream ?

Thank you for your advises, and to provide the supporting documentation if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping is not allowed, you must use the Graph API: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

About Page posts, check out the docs for all the information you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed

Comment: Thank you luschn for your answer, it helped me to better understand my problem.